# Can WP multisite manage multiple ccTLDs

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

Simple query: can WP multisite manage different ccTLDs not just subdirectories/domains. And map these ccTLDS within the network?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a router of sorts yourself, but the work has been done over at WPMU. I've used this before with great success! Try out Multi-Domains for WP Multisite.

[https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-domains/](https://premium.wpmudev.org/project/multi-domains)

Comment: Why wouldn't it work just like normal domain mapping - just edit the site URL in the network sites admin page.  Why do you need a plugin for this?

Comment: why would you need the plugin? this supposed to be core functionality

Comment: @MarkKaplun Mapping multiple TLDs is not core functionality.

Comment: it is since 4.2, just not very obvious how to do it. but maybe it depends on definion on mapping.... for sure adding a domain is supported, never checked how the network admin works

Comment: @MarkKaplun Would rather not use plugin, didn't realise it was a core function! Thought you could only add sub directories/domains in network sites admin and not TLD's. How do you add a TLD? Cheers.

Comment: @HarryJellicoe, in theory you can just add a full domain name where you would usually add the subdomain name. I am just never done it and I am not sure what are the implications regarding network admin access to the front and backend of that site, is it "transparent (meaning there is some cookie magic somewhere), or is a login to the specific site needed. sorry I can't be more helpful, but I didn't try it myself.,